# MU-MIMO net controller soft fails

Tags: networking

I have a computer which is about one year old, Acer V5.

I notice throughout my day the wifi will just sort of fail, the wifi signal will look good but no data shall pass, and I have to restart it.

I do a lot of skype calls, and it would be extremely rare to have the signal lost during those, so its only like it fails during downtime, when no requests are coming.

I am wondering whether it might be my component or the wifi router? Or maybe a configuration problem. This seems to have started right around the time I got a new wifi router from my isp, not meaning its new but new to me.

Anyway any advice would be welcome

Comment: Check the wireless encryption settings at the router and make sure it is WPA2-AES.

Comment: encryption settings look fine

Comment: Ok update is, I changed ISPs which of course means a new router and the problem is gone 100%, not even a hint of poor data transfer.

So, I suppose the reason was a failing router, it could have been a configuration issue though, I guess. Thanks to @MichaelBay for the help